# ReferenceError: privateSpecialRepair is not defined

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am getting this error on sentry. I don't know how or why the next/router is redirecting users to the same page, it is happening on some browsers, and on some browsers, it is working just fine.

[image]

Tags

```json
{
  "routing.instrumentation": "next-router"
}
```

Operation - pageLoad

Comment: Are you getting this error from Android devices? Got same issue here but my project is php

Comment: hi @EasonLin, i got this error from android device too, have u found the solution for this error?

Comment: Facing similar issue , did you get more info or solution for this error?

Comment: @ikbalmaulana unfortunatly I haven't found any solutions here, hope someone will.

Comment: Facing this issue as well with nuxt.js and affected users are on Chrome Mobile WebView 87.0.4280 on Android devices (Android 10 to 12)

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue with Chrome mobile webview 87.0.4280 on Android 9, 10 and 11

Comment: I'm seeing this on a site that isn't built on react or next.js. I suspect for us it's a javascript error from a browser extension that is just getting caught in our global error handler. We are seeing it only very very rarely though.

Comment: I am seeing this error too. We are using react but not next.js. All of the errors is happening on Chrome Mobile WebView and a wide range of Vivo devices only

Answer (score 7):

It looks like this has to do specifically with the Vivo OEM browser.
The current Vivo is based on Chrome 87 (2020).

I ended up on some Chinese dev blogs etc detailing similar errors with the same message.
Those seem to have been due to Vivo not handling new ES6 features.  Not certain exactly what is not supported in the current version that's causing this.

We're looking at adding filtering around the `<anonymous>` file in the stack trace since (as far as I can tell) that's always 3rd party scripts throwing up.