# Strange error processRandomSelector is not defined in React App

Tags: reactjs, sentry

Strange error

```
processRandomSelector is not defined
```

in React App

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71576916/12057512 What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the website
   https://polyfill.io/v3/url-builder/
2. Choosing checkboxes polyfill lib

- Intl
- es6
- String.prototype.replaceAll

3. Insert the script in index.html to your app
   [image]