# ReferenceError: processRandomSelector is not defined

Tags: android, google-chrome, exception, sentry

I suddenly started to get an error on my sentry logs for two particular errors... it appeared all of the them are from **Chrome Mobile WebView 87.0.4280  on Android**:

Following are the two screenshots that i am facing:

1. **Unexpected identifier**

[image: unexpected identifier]

2. **processRandomSelector is not defined**

[image: processRandomSelector is not defined]

Looking to hear if there is any solution to the problem or its a known bug that others are facing

Comment: where's the code where the errors are coming from?

Comment: Issue is we cant tract what part of our code the error is coming... as we dont have any processRandomSelector... it just started coming up in sentry logs today..
plus the as in the screenshot the source is anonymous..

Comment: And the source for the first application is some angular app, which is not the tech we are using...

Comment: it might be some library that your code is using, I don't see how to fix this without realizing where the error comes from. Perhaps an update broke some lib dependencies. But if it happens through your code, perhaps you can debug it and figure out where it comes from

Comment: nope we havent deployed anything on the app.. its looks like more towards a particular android device which is using chrome webview of version 87... since all the errors happedning are on the andoird and on the same version too... if it would be an issue in code then different device and os should also be in error logs

Comment: Oh I see. I don't really know sentry. But your app is breaking right? Something breaks in YOUR code when a device with webview 87 uses it no? In any case you need to be able to recreate this problem/ fix some code/ some configuration/ something to solve this. Can you use a device which produces the error and debug it? Or can you see better stack traces with line numbers etc?

Comment: Thats not clear if my code is breaking or is something with this particular android device...

Comment: We don't know the particular device too,as in the screenshot it only shows Generic Smartphone 

Comment: So posted to generally find out if happening to others too or it's just me...  Moreover, sentry is exception handler that logs error when any exception is fired.. so sometimes it also catches error from native device or if on browser then from extensions too

Comment: here one more question i found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73541968/strange-error-processrandomselector-is-not-defined-in-react-app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71228490/referenceerror-privatespecialrepair-is-not-defined/71576916#71576916

Answer (score 0):

These messages come from VivoBrowser or an Add-On for this Browser, which uses own injected JS-Code on web pages viewed.

The UserAgent we saw:
"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 12; V2029; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Mobile Safari/537.36 VivoBrowser/9.3.0.1"